# Perl Hash to CSV

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing, csv, hash

I have a data file for alarms occuring during the day. The format looks like

```
2014/04/27-23:42:22.177742- Alarm1
2014/04/27-23:42:22.177744- Alarm2
2014/04/27-23:42:22.177747- Alarm3
2014/04/27-23:42:22.177749- Alarm1
```

Now I cant guess when any alarm would appear. it depends on the system. What I have done is to insert the data of alarm (e.g Alarm1) into a 2D hash. I take a chunk of 5 minutes everytime and look for alarm that appeared during the 5 minutes. I would add the value into hash, everytime I find a new alarm. In case of a repetition (like Alarm1 above) I would simply add 1 to the value. So in the end it would give me a hash which contains the alarm name and the times it appeared in 5 minutes.
Next I would start processing the next 5 minutes.

I am processing it for the whole day, so it is possible that 1 alarm can start appearing 10 in the morning, so It would be a new entry in to the hash. Now ehen I try to print the values eventually to a CSV, its a mess. Totally makes no sense. What I expect is a csv which should look like

```
Name,00:00,00:05,00:10,
Alarm1,2,5,2,7,
Alarm2,4,7,3,6
Alarm3,6,1,6,3
...
```

My code is:

```
use Time::Local;
use POSIX 'strftime';
use Data::Dumper;


my %outputHash= ();

$curr = timelocal(0, 0, 0, (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[1], (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[0]-1, (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[-1]);
$currentTime = strftime "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S", localtime($curr);
for ($count = 1; $count <= 288; $count++) { #there are 288 '5 minutes' in a day.
    $curr += 300;
    $nextTime = strftime "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S", localtime($curr);
        $cmd = "awk '\$0>=from&&\$0<=to' from=\"$currentTime\" to=\"$nextTime\" Output.txt";
            my $dataChunk = qx($cmd);
            my @lines = split /[\n]+/, $dataChunk;
        foreach my $line (@lines) {
            chomp;
            $timeStamp1 = substr($line,21,6);
            #print "\n$timeStamp1\n$error\n";
            if ($timeStamp1 != $timeStamp2){
                $outputHash{$error}{$count} = $outputHash{$error}{$count} + 1;
            }
            $ind = index($line,'- ') + 2;
            $len = length($line) - $ind;
            $error = substr($line,$ind, $len);
            $timeStamp2 = $timeStamp1;
        }
    $currentTime = $nextTime;
#   if ($count>3){$count=300;}
}
`>/tmp/report.txt`;
open (MYFILE, '>>/tmp/report.txt'); 
my @outputArray = ();
my $flag =1;
foreach my $error (sort keys %outputHash)
{
    print MYFILE "$error,";
    #$outputArray[$flag][0] = $error;
    for ($count=1,$count <= 288, $count++)
    {
        print MYFILE "$outputHash{$error}{$count},";
        #$outputArray[$flag][$count] = int($outputHash{$error}{$count});
    }
    $flag += 1;print MYFILE "\n";
}
close (MYFILE);
#print Dumper(\@outputArray);
exit;
```

A simplified display of my has looks like this. The reason its haphazard is because Alarm 1 occurred only in '2nd' 5 minutes interval, Alarm 2 occured in 1st only, Alarm 3 occured in 4 consecutive 5 minutes intervals we monitored.

```
'Alarm1{
    '2' => '5'
  },
'Alarm2{
    '1' => '1'
  },
'Alarm3
'4' => '1',
'1' => '2',
'3' => '1',
'2' => '1'
   },
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of your hash?

Comment: just edited it to include the hash

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, its best if you use a module that is meant for dealing with CSV.

I chose `Class::CSV` because it is is simple to use.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Class::CSV;

my %hash = (
    'Alarm1' => {'2' => '5', },
    'Alarm2' => {'1' => '1', },
    'Alarm3' => {
        '4' => '1',
        '1' => '2',
        '3' => '1',
        '2' => '1'
      },
);
my @fields = qw/AlarmNo 00:00:00 00:05:00 00:10:00 00:15:00/;
my $csv = Class::CSV->new( fields => \@fields );

#make the hash into a suitable array

my @array;
my @keys = keys %hash;

for my $i (0 .. $#keys){
        push @{ $array[$i] }, $keys[$i];
        for my $inter (1 .. 4){
            my $val = '';
            if(exists $hash{$keys[$i]}->{$inter}){
                $val = $hash{$keys[$i]}->{$inter};
            }
            push @{ $array[$i] }, $val;
        }
}

$csv->add_line($_) for(@array);
print join(',', @fields), "\n"; #Just to make it tidy on the commandline
$csv->print();
```

So you would use `print MYFILE $csv->string` to get it into your file.

Edit:

If you can't install Class::CSV check out Text::CSV which may be installed by default.

You can also join the arrays by a comma like so

```
for(@array){
    print join(',', @{$_});
}
```

Comment: For certain reasons, i cant install Class::CSV. How can i use this library without installing it? Putting it in the directory of the script?

Comment: @user3195304 check out Text::CSV which comes with you're Perl install. Ill edit my answer to add using join to make the csv

Comment: On a totally another note, I am using #!/usr/bin/perl
use lib '/tmp/report/modules';
and the Class::CSV is in there, but it cant locate it somehow. weird.

Comment: One more thing, My hash insertion isn't working as well. What I need is to add entries into hash on the fly. Lets say I encounter "Alarm1" string while reading the text file. I will have to insert into hash. What I am doing right now is " $outputHash{"$error"}{"$count"} = $outputHash{"$error"}{"$count"} + 1; " ... Where $error is the "Alarm1" & $count is the interval. I add +1 to the value whenever I encounter a new instance.